# Как вывести значения в столбик, используя один print()

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
x1 = True
x2 = False
x3 = True
x4 = True
print(x1, "\n", x2, "\n", x3, "\n", x4)
```

Если так написать, то добавляются лишние пробелы в начале.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Укажите `\n` как разделитель.

***Пример:***

```py
x1, x2, x3, x4 = True, False, True, True
print(x1, x2, x3, x4, sep='\n')
```

***stdout:***

```py
True
False
True
True
```

Answer (score 0):

`print(str(x1)+"\n"+str(x2))`
и далее